# Telegram api send frequently message to our api

Tags: asp.net, https, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a problem with telegram bot api.
when i was set webhook,then one of client send a photo to our bot and telegram api send frequently obejct of this photo to our api with the same update_id

this is answer from telegram support: 
**most probably issue is that you are not answering with a "2XX" to our requests, so we are sending the same updete as we understand that it wasn't received.**

whats problem?!

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide some codes.

Comment: @hamidrezashokouhi have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu yes, i have resolved. in my api after some process ,there is  an error and this error cause return code 500 to telegram api. I have just solved this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not returning the proper status code (200) to Telegram so it thinks you did not receive the message successfully.

Comment: I have an errors in my api , so return status code 500 to telegram api

Comment: and how we can return status code(200) to telegram ? can u give us a little example ?